# how to show current command in tmux pane title

Tags: bash, tmux

I would like to update the tmux pane-title with the current executing command or, if no command, the name of the current shell. What I've come up with so far is this, in bashrc:

```
case ${TERM} in

  screen*)       
    PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]2;bash\033\\"'
    set -o functrace
    trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;$BASH_COMMAND\033\\"' DEBUG
    ;;

   ...

esac
```

the method was derived from here:
http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash.html

This partially works - it does what is needed but causes other problems: the first prompt in a new shell is prefixed with

```
"'"' DEBUG"
```

and all remaining commands with

```
"
```

It also prevents some commands given on the command line to fail, for example:

```
$ ps -h $$
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
```

So, while the above does allow the current command to be displayed in the tmux pane title, it does not work. Has anyone else got a better solution to this, or a suggestion as to what is wrong with the above?

Thanks.

Comment: would you mind to give an example of what output you'd like to have after typing some command?

Comment: basically whatever is running in a (bash) tmux pane should be reflected in the pane title. So if I entered, say, "vim ~/.bashrc" then the pane title would read ""vim ~/.bashrc". when that command finished and the bash prompt returns, the pane title would read "bash". This is what the above does, it just has some other undesirable side-effects which I tried to describe in my question.

Comment: I don't know what version of `tmux` you're using, but there was no change in my pane-title bar (the one by the bottom of the page). I'm using `tmux 1.6`.

Comment: I'm using tmux 1.7. To see the pane title in the status bar you have to put #T somwhere in the format string for the status line in ".tmux.conf". I've been doing some testing and I think using 'functrace' somehow messes up rvm and that is what's causing the problems. I need to do more investigating though...

Comment: I guess I can't help you, then. Just one last thing: did you really mean to use `trap '... $BASH_COMMAND ...'`, even though you're setting value for `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: Yes, I did mean $BASH_COMMAND. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to have the tmux pane title updated every time you execute a command in BASH. Put code like the below in `~/.bashrc`:

```
case ${TERM} in

    screen*)

        # user command to change default pane title on demand
        function title { TMUX_PANE_TITLE="$*"; }

        # function that performs the title update (invoked as PROMPT_COMMAND)
        function update_title { printf "\033]2;%s\033\\" "${1:-$TMUX_PANE_TITLE}"; }

        # default pane title is the name of the current process (i.e. 'bash')
        TMUX_PANE_TITLE=$(ps -o comm $$ | tail -1)

        # Reset title to the default before displaying the command prompt
        PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'update_title'   

        # Update title before executing a command: set it to the command
        trap 'update_title "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG

        ;;

        ... other cases for different terminals ...

esac
```

}

The function `update_title` prints the escape sequence that changes the tmux pane title. It sets the pane title to the default (the value of `$TMUX_PANE_TITLE`) or to whatever is given as an argument.

The function `title` is for end-user convenience: it changes the value of the default title in `$TMUX_PANE_TITLE`. The end user can at any time change the title to whever they want by doing:

```
$ title my new pane title
```

The initial title is set to the name of the running shell (i.e. 'bash').

Bash executes anything in `$PROMPT_COMMAND` prior to displaying a prompt. This is set so that the `update_title` function gets executed before every prompt to set the prompt to the default title.

The trap causes Bash to execute `$BASH_COMMAND` before executing any command. It is set so that the `update_title` function gets executed before every command to set the prompt to the text of that command.

Other notes

- while working this out, I discovered that `set -o functrace` or `set -T` (as described by person linked to in the question) causes RVM to break. The reason for it being suggested was to allow prompts to change in subshells but the lack of this wasn't a problem to me.
- To get the initial title, I wanted to use the more succinct `ps -ho comm $$` but this seemed to not work inside tmux with the above in place. I am not sure why so opted for something else that did work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can set it as the title of a pane if it isn't already (It looks like on my tmux 1.8 it already states the command as the title of the pane), but there is the undocumented `#{pane_current_command}` variable that you may use in your status bar string that will contain the command.

Comment: It is no longer undocumented, it's in the manpage under FORMATS.

Comment: it is still unreliable. It reports garbage when used in conditional parsing: `:display '#{pane_current_command}'` (vim) && `:%if #{==:#{pane_current_command},vim} select-pane -T "vim" %else select-pane -T "bullshit" %endif` (bullshit), tmux 3.3a

Comment: I don't use `#{pane_current_command}` because you are correct that it is unreliable. I am not sure what to do about this answer because I want to edit it but it's gonna need a very drastic edit. Anyway, for a few years now what I drive is the following: (1) configure your shell (for me, zsh) to report what you want it to report (the last command run, usually, and flexibility exists here so you can make your apps report more status in real time), (2) let tmux transparently handle the title (3) configure tmux to put the `#{pane_title}` where you want it (`status-right`, `pane-border-format`...)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could use this one-liner function to prefix your commands in tmux:

```
panewrap () { printf "\033]2;%s\033\\" "$1"; "$@"; }
```

it will set the pane title to launche command (`$1` - command name) and pass on it execution to terminal (`$@` - command name and all of its parameters).

The inconvenience is that you have to prefix an additional word before any command, but I do it occasionally, only when command is intended to run for quite a while (e.g., tail).